# How to write the Revision details into a file?

Tags: c#, tortoisesvn

I need to write the revision details of SVN log into a file.

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/command:log /path:" + updateLocation + " /startrev:{2016-12-19} /endrev:{2016-11-11}";
```

I can get the revision details of particular date ranges but how to write/save this into file? because i need to retrieve the revision number alone from that revision details. Please suggest me your ideas.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the software, however their [documentation](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html) states:

> If /outfile:path\to\file is specified, the selected revisions are written to that file when the log dialog is closed. The revisions are written in the same format as is used to specify revisions in the merge dialog.

Wait for the process to be completed and then it should automatically save it in the `/outfile:` that you've specified in the arguments.
Hope this helped!

Comment: but the all revision histories should be in selected state to save into that file. So we have to select all revisions. It is not i want.

Comment: Does it select them when you add the "/startrev:{2016-12-19} /endrev:{2016-11-11}" arguments?

Comment: No. By default, the first revision is selected ,remaining are not selected. How to also remaining revisions also?